# How to set default or optional parameters in scheme?

Tags: scheme, lisp

I'm trying to figure out how to how to set default or optional parameters in Scheme.

I've tried `(define (func a #!optional b) (+ a b))` but I can't find of a way to check if `b` is a default parameter, because simply calling `(func 1 2)` will give the error:

```
Error: +: number required, but got #("halt") [func, +]
```

I've also tried `(define (func a [b 0]) (+ a b))` but I get the following error:

```
Error: execute: unbound symbol: "b" [func]
```

If it helps I'm using [BiwaScheme](http://www.biwascheme.org/index.html) as used in [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/scheme)

Comment: search for "optional" on http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-language. (found it just by googling "Scheme optional arguments").

Answer (score 3):

This works fine in Racket:

```
(define (func a (b 0)) ; same as [b 0]
  (+ a b))
```

For example:

```
(func 4)
=> 4
(func 3 2)
=> 5
```

...But it's not standard syntax, it depends on the Scheme interpreter being used. There's syntax for handling a variable number of arguments, it can be used to handle optional arguments with default values, but it won't look as pretty:

```
(define (func a . b)
  (+ a (if (null? b) 0 (car b))))
```

How does it work? `b` is a *list* of arguments. If it's empty use zero, otherwise use the value of the first element.

Comment: Huh, I never noticed before that the answer to this question is almost the same in Scheme as it is in C (that you options are "no", "list" or "macro"). That says something about both, but not sure what.

Comment: @Leushenko Yeah, there's a great beauty in Scheme's arglist processing, but also a great inconvenience.  The flexibility to get the whole list means that you can process it however you like, but it also means that you get to process it however you like.  :\

Answer (score 1):

Check if your Scheme implementation supports [SRFI 89: Optional positional and named parameters](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-89/srfi-89.html).

Answer (score 0):

MIT/GNU Scheme [doc](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Lambda-Expressions.html#Lambda-Expressions) for this purpose.

```lisp
(define (f a #!optional b)
  (+ a
     (if (default-object? b)
         0
         b)))

; test
(f 1) ; 1
(f 1 2) ; 3
```