# passing known arguments to Scheme function

Tags: scheme

I have a function `primeFactors` that I want to take in a number, and return a list of the factors of the number. It appears that

`(define (primeFactors x '()) ...FOOBAR)`

is invalid, however the workaround of

`(define (primeFactors x) (primeFactors2 x '()))`

with `primeFactors2` defined elsewhere would work, because I can *pass* the empty list as an argument when calling the function but not defining it. Is there a less awful way of doing this kind of predetermined argument passing?

Comment: Are you wanting to have a function with an optional argument that uses a default value if it's omitted when called? If so... you didn't mention *which* scheme you're using, but many popular ones support that with DSSSL style parameter lists or other syntax that does the same thing.

Comment: In your specific case, you could also use `(lambda (x . rest))`.

Comment: See "[How to set default or optional parameters in scheme?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36213204/402322)" and "[Scheme - Optional arguments and default values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36914415/402322)".

Comment: The "less awful" way is delegating to a locally defined function. This avoids polluting the interface with something that is purely internal state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R7RS-Small and R6RS has `case-lambda` in the library `(scheme case-lambda)` and `(rnrs control 6)`:

```scm
#!r7rs
(import (scheme base)
        (scheme case-lambda))

(define prime-factors
  (case-lambda
    ((n) (prime-factors n '()))
    ((n lst) 'implementation)))
```

For R5RS we have [SRFI-89 Positional arguments](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-89/srfi-89.html). Perhaps your favorite implementation has it already and if not you can just fetch it from the spec. Here is how it works:

```scm
#!r5rs
(define* (prime-factors x (lst '()))
  'implementation)
```

A pure compatible Scheme way to do it:

```scm
;;; (prim-factors n [lst '()]) => lst
(define (prime-factors n . llst)
  (define (prime-factors n lst)
     'implementation)
  (prime-factors n (if (null? llst) '() (car llst))))
```

The local function is just to make it more efficient in the case you are doing recursions since it's only the initial call that is without the second argument.